# Shell if statement based on cammand output/completion

Tags: bash, shell

I have trawled the internet for this answer, but alas couldn't find one.

In PHP I can run a command inside an if block, like so

```
if(command(blah)) {} else {}
```

As each function will return a truthy/falsey value. Can I do the same in a shell script? I want to echo output based on whether a command runs correctly. The commend to run is:

```
find . -type d -exec sudo chmod -R 775 {} \\;
```

I want to output that it ran successfully, or failed, then move on to another command.

Could I run the command into a variable or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shell commands typically return an exit code indicating success or failure, with `0` indicating success and anything else indicating some sort of error (the specifics will depend on what command you're running).

You can test for this exit code in an if statement:

```
if my_command; then
  echo It worked.
fi
```

And you can also chain commands together using the `||` and `&&` operators.

```
my_command && echo It worked.
my_command || echo It failed.
```

Your specific example with the `find` command is a little tricky.  The `chmod` command might fail, but the `find` command will still complete "successfully".  Something like this might help:

```
find . -type d -exec sudo sh -c 'chmod -R 775 {} || echo "FAILED {}"' \;
```

This will print...

```
FAILED ./path/to/directory
```

...for any place it fails, so you could check the output.  But I'm not sure that's absolutely necessary.  There are few situations where your command is going to fail: e.g., on a read-only filesystem, or possibly on an NFS mount.

Comment: Thank you for a very concise answer! I shall modify my commands and script accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My take would be:

```
find . -type d|while read directory
do
  chmod -R 755 ${directory}
  if [ $? = 0 ];then
     echo "successfully changed ${directory}
  else
     echo "Did not change ${directory}
  fi
done
```

This breaks it up and is more readable and you can test for each command. $? is the variable that is filled in with success (0) or failure (1 or greater)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although also correct, I chose the answer with a more concise explanation.

Comment: No problem, its the Python geek in me that likes more readability :)